# jquery tabs cache and ajax tabs does not work kendo grid

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, kendo-grid, jquery-tabs

I am using Jquery tabs for show pages that retrieve with ajax.For prevent loading page whenever I select tab, I am using "cache:true" in tab settings.when I open First tab with grid or other component anything work well.After open second tab, second tab work well but some functionality such as Kendo Grid of first page does not work And after open third tab,pre two tabs does not work and so on.

```
 $("#tabs").tabs({

    cache: true,
    scrollable: true,
    collapsible: false
});
```

///////////////EDIT//////////////
When I want to use pre tab I get this error about Kendo Grid :
 *Cannot call method 'dataItem' of undefined*